# Navigating JSON data in c#

Tags: c#, json.net

I'm trying to check if a twitch.tv stream is online or not via c#.  Currently I have:

```
    private bool checkStream(String chan)
    {
        using (var w = new WebClient()) {

            String json_data = w.DownloadString("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/" + chan);
            JObject stream = JObject.Parse(json_data);
            print(json_data); //just for testing purposes
            if (stream["stream"] != null)
            {
                print("YIPPEE");
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Here's the twitch JSON API for what I'm downloading: https://github.com/justintv/Twitch-API/blob/master/v2_resources/streams.md#get-streamschannel

As you can see, if a stream is currently offline, the `stream` field just says `null`.  But obviously, it's still there, so my `if(stream["stream"]!=null)` check doesn't work.  Never used JSON or Newtonsoft's json.net before, so I'm kind of at a loss for what to do.  Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Where are you setting your breakpoint?  When you debug, what are the values of `chan` and `json_data`?

Comment: @brian: Sorry, this obviously isn't the entire code for the program. chan is the correct string that I want to check, and I'm getting the correct JSON data back.

Comment: This might be stating the obvious but if you break on the line "if (stream["stream"] != null)" and put a watch on "stream["stream"]", what do you see when the stream is offline? Figure that out and check for that value instead of null.

Comment: @Brian: For reference, some tests: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=jAJQjpA4  As you can see, the streams field of the JSON request has much more information when the stream is live.  However, in my snippet above, "YIPPEE" prints for both channels.

Comment: Instead of comparing the actual value of stream["stream"] you can do a stream["stream"].HasValues which will tell you if there are child tokens, when the value is null that will be false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this. The HasValues is a bool property that checks if there are child tokens, if its value is null there will not be any child tokens.

```
if (stream["stream"].HasValues)
{
    print("YIPPEE");
}else
{
    print("No Stream");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a class that you can de-serialize the json to.  For instance, if you receive json that looks like this

```
MyJson = {
   Prop1 : "Property1",
   Prop2 : "Property2"
}
```

then you'll need to create a class that acts as a contract between your program and the JSON stream.

```
public class MyJsonClass{
   public string Prop1;
   public string Prop2;

   public MyJsonClass(){
   }
}
```

Now, you can deserialize the json to your C# class and check it for any null values:

```
// Create a MyJson class instance by deserializing your json string
string myJsonString = ...//get your json string
MyJsonClass deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyJsonClass>(myJsonString);

if ( deserialized.Prop1 == null )
   //etc etc etc
```

Comment: I thought the JObject's Linq parse did that implicitly? What I mean is, the code "works".  My JObject named stream has a "stream" field from the JSON already parsed into it.

Comment: Just wanted to add, while working with converting complex JSON with multiple child nodes into a C# class, http://json2csharp.com/ is very useful!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a full processor for that Json response (**Disclaimer:** I used http://json2csharp.com/ for this code ) :

```
public class Links
{
    public string channel { get; set; }
    public string self { get; set; }
}

public class Links2
{
    public string self { get; set; }
}

public class Links3
{
    public string stream_key { get; set; }
    public string editors { get; set; }
    public string subscriptions { get; set; }
    public string commercial { get; set; }
    public string videos { get; set; }
    public string follows { get; set; }
    public string self { get; set; }
    public string chat { get; set; }
    public string features { get; set; }
}

public class Channel
{
    public string display_name { get; set; }
    public Links3 _links { get; set; }
    public List<object> teams { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string created_at { get; set; }
    public string logo { get; set; }
    public string updated_at { get; set; }
    public object mature { get; set; }
    public object video_banner { get; set; }
    public int _id { get; set; }
    public string background { get; set; }
    public string banner { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string game { get; set; }
}

public class Stream
{
    public Links2 _links { get; set; }
    public string broadcaster { get; set; }
    public string preview { get; set; }
    public long _id { get; set; }
    public int viewers { get; set; }
    public Channel channel { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string game { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Links _links { get; set; }
    public Stream stream { get; set; }
}
```

and here's how to use it :

```
bool StreamOnline = false;
using (var w = new WebClient())
{

    var jsonData = w.DownloadData("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/" +  + chan);
    var s = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(RootObject));
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream(jsonData))
    {
        var obj = (RootObject)s.ReadObject(ms);
        StreamOnline = obj.stream == null;
    }

}
return StreamOnline;
```

Please note that you need to reference `System.Runtime.Serialization` and add `using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;` to use `DataContractJsonSerializer`. If you don't need every detail just make the `stream` property of type `object` (in the `RootObject` class)  and check whether it's `null` or not.

Comment: Thanks for this solution.  I was going to use it but I read down and saw the simpler solution for what I had already implemented while referencing Newtonsoft.Json.dll.  I'll bookmark this in case I ever need more information than a simple boolean for online/offline.